# Update a "main" table from an "update" table while ignoring nulls, blanks, or empty fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a main table that I am trying to update from a table that only has fields populated that need to be updated in the main table, using a unique ID to ensure I am updating only matched records. Here is what the SQL string looks like for the query:

```
UPDATE [tblMain] INNER JOIN tblUpdate ON tblMain.UUID = tblUpdate.UUID
SET tblMain.contractName = tblUpdate.contractName
WHERE ((tblUpdate.contractName) IS NOT NULL);
```

The idea is to only pull the fields from the update table that actually have data, and ignore the fields that are either NULL, blank, or empty. To be clear, I want to include ALL records in the tbleUpdate, but only update with the fields that contain data. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to UPDATE one table from another in MS Access, you should do this

```
UPDATE tblMain, tblUpdate 
SET tblMain.contractName = tblUpdate.contractName
WHERE tblMain.UUID = tblUpdate.UUID
  AND tblUpdate.contractName IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: That makes sense. Sorry if this changes then answer a little, but I have multiple columns I am trying to update. I don't think adding the columns with more ANDs is the right way, is it?

Comment: Could I use an IS NOT NULL in the SET to only allow changes where the field is not null?

Comment: Accepted as partial answer. For the time being I have created separate update queries for each field and am calling them via VBA depending on what needs to be updated. Thank you for your time.